# Get the media file from SharePoint after getting a callRecord notification

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have subscribed to /communications/callRecords to get notifications whenever a call is available in Teams. At the moment the call is saved in SharePoint under the Recordings folder.
Is there a way in the Microsoft Graph API to link the callRecord to a file in SharePoint Drive to download it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the above feature is not available. Rather you may want to subscribe to callrecords and see if it provides the location or not.